# html_entity_decode make mystery manipulation with html-string

Tags: php, php-7

have a variable

```
$out = "&lt;h4&gt;Edit User-Bundle Configuration&lt;/h4&gt;
&lt;p&gt;
Open file application/config/routes.php. Here you find:
&lt;pre&gt;$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome'&lt;/pre&gt;
&lt;/p&gt;";
```

when i do

```
html_entity_decode($out);
```

now i expect

```
<h4>Edit User-Bundle Configuration</h4> 
<p> Open file application/config    /routes.php. Here you find:
<pre>$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome'</pre> 
</p>
```

but it will give out

```
<h4>Edit User-Bundle Configuration</h4>
<p> Open file application/config/routes.php. Here you find: </p>
<pre>$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome'</pre>
<p></p>
```

Comment: This code would throw an error because you have a variable $route inside double-quotes. Also not clear why you expect a bunch of spaces before "/routes.php".

Comment: What's your PHP version? Also, it throws parse error with the code exactly as you posted. When I add a backslash before dollar sign, seems to be working OK: https://3v4l.org/lv0nW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misdiagnosed the problem. The PHP will output the code you expect.

The code you think it outputs is the result of passing that to a browser, rendering it as HTML and then looking at the DOM (instead of viewing the source).

This is because the browser is performing error recovery.

A `<pre>` element is **forbidden** from appearing inside a `<p>` element. [Paragraphs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) may contain only [phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) (which does not include `<pre>` elements).

You can see this if you skip the PHP and go straight to your desired HTML:

```html
<h4>Edit User-Bundle Configuration</h4> 
<p> Open file application/config    /routes.php. Here you find:
<pre>$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome'</pre> 
</p>
```

Screenshot of the resulting DOM, in Chrome, from the above snippet:

[image: DOM]

Comment: useful related link for [`<pre>` element specs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)